# Thickbox in Plugin settings page?

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, thickbox

I adding the default wordpress thickbox in the admin page to show some information inside the div. Everything seems ok when i click that link it appear in popup now

```
<a class="thickbox" href="#TB_inline?height=300&amp;width=400&amp;inlineId=simple_div" title="Select Bar Style"  >Popup Load</a>
```

But actually what i am trying is to show this popup when that plugin settings page load.
I tried this way like what i mentioned here is

```
<script language="javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    tb_show("testing", "#TB_inline?height=300&amp;width=400&amp;inlineId=simple_div");
  });
</script>
```

But it shows like dim in settings page of my plugin how can i show the div content inside the popup automatically on settings page load.

Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: Not `document.ready`, use `window.load` or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1236040/1287812).

Comment: Thanks @brasofilo that idea you are proposing is works for me I updated my ans what i did exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script language="javascript">
  jQuery(window).load(function() {
    tb_show("testing", "#TB_inline?height=300&amp;width=400&amp;inlineId=simple_div");
  });
</script>
```

Hi According to the [brasofilo](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/12615/brasofilo) suggestion I did this and make it as workable